# how to stack series in nvd3 multibar angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

i want to create a multiple bar chart with nvd3 angularjs directive by cmaurer ([nvd3 directive link](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/multi.bar.chart.html)) but the problem is that i need to stack some series and there is a strange bug. here is my data:

```
 $scope.exampleData = [
                {
                    "key": "Monto Inicial",
                    "values": [[0, $scope.planAhorro.MontoInicial]]
                }, {
                    "key": "Monto Periodico",
                    "values": [[0, $scope.planAhorro.MontoPeriodico]]
                }, {
                    "key": "Total Sueños",
                    "values": [[1, $scope.planAhorro.Valor]]
                }];
```

i want to get 2 bars with the values of `$scope.planAhorro.MontoInicial` and `$scope.planAhorro.MontoPeriodico` stacked, and the another bar with the value `$scope.planAhorro.Valor` alone, but the thing is the first 2 stack well and the third stack on top and i don't need it to stack!!

and here is the output:

http://es.tinypic.com/r/2yvjnkw/8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you need to set up values for all range, in you case: for 0 and 1:

```
$scope.exampleData = [
            {
                "key": "Monto Inicial",
                "values": [[0, $scope.planAhorro.MontoInicial], [1, 0]],
                "color": "red" 
            }, {
                "key": "Monto Periodico",
                "values": [[0, $scope.planAhorro.MontoPeriodico], [1, 0]],
                "color": "green"
            }, {
                "key": "Total Sueños",
                "values": [[0, ], [1, $scope.planAhorro.Valor]],
                "color": "#0000FF" //blue
            }];
```

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UYCpjy?p=preview), but I use [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) directive instead.

Comment: Thanks!!!! this was so helpful, can i ask you something else? how can i  give different colors for every element in the serie, and not by serie

Comment: just add keyword "color" to each json element in your `exampleData` array, like: [{"key": "...", "values": [...], "color": "red"}, ...]. I updated demo.

Comment: hi, thats a nice example but im trying to give a different color for every element in the serie, not the whole group, and in the page i found an attribute named barColor but i can't make it work, whanks in advance

Comment: yea, `barColor` actually does this. One way is to use an array, like `barColor: ["yellow", "blue"]`, see [demo1](http://plnkr.co/edit/3OR2Ik?p=preview). Another way is to use random colors, defined by the function like `barColor: function(d,i){ ... return randomcolor }`, see [demo2](http://plnkr.co/edit/TwKry8?p=preview).